# Mapping an action name to a class type in C++

Tags: c++, containers

I want to link a bunch of 'action' strings to single 'parent' string but there could be multiple strings that own 'action' strings.

```
map<string, string> ctType;

ctType.insert(pair<string, string>("1")("default"));

ctType.insert(pair<string, string>("2")("register"));
ctType.insert(pair<string, string>("2")("addaddress"));

ctType.insert(pair<string, string>("3")("request"));
```

What is the best way to complete this?

Comment: Have a look at `std::multimap`...

Comment: _"What is the best way to complete this?"_ -- This can't be answered in general, because it depends on your requirements (which you didn't state). Even then, there will be many different opinions.

Answer (score 1):

You could either (1) use `std::multimap`, or you could (2) use a map with containers as its elements. Variant (1) is rather short, but has the drawback that it is harder to control how the "multiple entries" behave in terms of, for example, duplicates; and its probably harder to implement a "nested loop" over the keys and each of its values. Decide on your own:

```
int main() {

    std::multimap<int, std::string> m;

    m.insert({1,"First0"});
    m.insert({1,"First0"});
    m.insert({1,"First1"});
    m.insert({3,"Third"});

    for (auto& p : m) {
        auto key = p.first;
        auto val = p.second;

        cout << key << ":" << val << endl;
    }

    std::map<int,std::set<std::string>> m2;
    m2[1].insert("First0");
    m2[1].insert("First0");
    m2[1].insert("First1");
    m2[3].insert("Third");

    for (auto& p : m2) {
        auto key = p.first;
        auto set = p.second;

        cout << key << ":" << endl;
        for (auto &val : set) {
            cout << " " << val << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1:First0
1:First0
1:First1
3:Third

1:
 First0
 First1
3:
 Third
```

Comment: How would this work if std::multimap<std::string, std::string> m;